# Only Admin Role Can Edit or Delete Notes Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a simple issue but nonetheless unable to figure it out. My employee role can not edit or delete notes but they can view them & they can also create them.

My admin role however can view, create, edit & delete.  My employee section is working but my admin is not. I am still new to rails so please bear with my ignorance.
My error is "NameError in Notes#index" and "undefined local variable or method `note' for #<#:0x007fa7b580c0a0>"

In my notes/index.html.erb file my code is as follows:

```
<% if @user.role == "employee" %>

    <%= link_to 'New Note', new_note_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
         <div class="row notes-row"><h1><%= note.title %></h1></div>
         <div class="row notes-row"><h3>Created By: </h3><%= note.user_name %></div>
         <div class="row notes-row"><h6>Posted On:</h6><%=note.created_at%></div>
         <div class="row notes-row"><%= note.text_box %></div>
         <br>
         <p><%= link_to 'View', note %></p>
         <br>
         <hr>
    <% end %>

<% elsif @user.role == "admin" %>
     <%= link_to 'Add New Job', new_job_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note) %><%= link_to 'Destroy', note, method: :delete, data: {             confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <br>
    <p> <% @notes.each do |note| %> | </p>
        <%= link_to 'View', note%>
    <%end%>
<% end%>
```

My index method is : 
   `def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = current_user
    @notes = Note.all
    @notes = Note.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 5)
  end`

Comment: At which line did the error shows up?

Comment: And also post your `index method` of your controller.

Comment: @Pavan posted my index method

Comment: But you didn't answer my question yet.

Comment: @Pavan Sorry it is the <%= link_to 'Edit'%> line where the action controller is catching the error

Comment: @Pavan thank you... now I have another error *sigh*

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: Off-topic: You MUST check on the server-side that the user's role is the proper one: If I am authenticated in your app as a simple "Employee", if I type by myself `/jobs/new` or `/jobs/5/edit`, I will have access to these pages (but you did not display the links to me). Make sure that you check the user's role in your controllers too.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I am very confused with my controllers right now. I know I need to fix them I am just confused. I have devise and cancan gems installed would you be able to provide some clarification if i post my controllwe?

Comment: If you are using CanCan, then you should not be using `if @user.role == "employee"` but something like `if @user.can?(:something)` where `:something` is a Rule defined in the Ability class. See CanCan's documentation about it

Comment: @MrYoshiji It all works thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error arises from this point;

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note) %><%= link_to 'Destroy', note, method: :delete, data: {             confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The variable `note` is unknown at this point.

You could re-factor it this way;

```
<% if @user.role == "employee" %>
    <%= link_to 'New Note', new_note_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
<% end %>

<% @notes.each do |note| %>
    <% if @user.role == "employee" %>
         <div class="row notes-row"><h1><%= note.title %></h1></div>
         <div class="row notes-row"><h3>Created By: </h3><%= note.user_name %></div>
         <div class="row notes-row"><h6>Posted On:</h6><%=note.created_at%></div>
         <div class="row notes-row"><%= note.text_box %></div>
         <br>
         <p><%= link_to 'View', note %></p>
         <br>
         <hr>
    <% end %>
    <% if @user.role == "admin" %>
        <%= link_to 'Add New Job', new_job_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note) %><%= link_to 'Destroy', note, method: :delete, data: {             confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %> 
<br>
<% if @user.role == "admin" %>
    <p> <% @notes.each do |note| %> | </p>
        <%= link_to 'View', note%>
    <%end%>
<% end %>
```

The code can be cleaned up further.

Comment: @CodingKat, i have shared a possible way of re-factoring.

Comment: Your double tests `if/end` on the user's role can be merged into one `if/elsif/end`

Comment: @Acacia now I have used your code, but I have the same links repeating themselves 4-5 times.

Comment: @CodingKat, i am not able to test it.It is just code i wrote off my head and can be improved alot.